# Laravel - Register don't send data to database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm on Laravel 5.4 and i'm trying to do a register page but data are not send in my databse... And i don't have any error.

Here is the controller : (Generate by Laravel)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\PostUser;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    protected $primaryKey = "id_biodiv_acteur";
    protected $table = "acteur";

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/pages/users';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname' => 'string|max:255',
             ...            
            'picture' => 'image'
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'nom' => $data['name'],
            'prenom' => $data['surname'],
             ...
            'image' => $data['picture']
        ]);
    }
}
```

My register.blade.php :

```
<div class="add-content container">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        <h1>&bull; Ajouter un utilisateur &bull;</h1>
        <div class="underline"></div>

        <form action="{!! route('register') !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" role="form">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <div class="column-left">

                <label class="has-float-label" for="name">
                    <input class="" type="text" placeholder="" name="name" required>
                    <span>Nom</span>
                </label>

                <label class="has-float-label" for="password">
                    <input class="" type="password" placeholder="" name="password" required>
                    <span>Mot de passe</span>
                </label>

                ...

                <label class="has-float-label" for="picture">
                    <input type="file" name="picture" multiple>
                    <span>Ajoutez des images</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="button">Enregistrer</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And a model i added to the controller (PostUser.php) :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class PostUser extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = "id_acteur";
    protected $table = "acteur";

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'prenom',
         ...
        'image'
    ];
}
```

Laravel created route for register :

```
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

But i haven't any function call register or showRegistrationForm in RegisterController

Comment: your model called `PostUser` in method create you are using `User`

Comment: let us to know what error displayed

Comment: @omadonex is right, see your model name and the name that you are using to create an user

Answer (score 1):

If `route('register')` goes to `RegisterController@create` method, you can get the user-entered data in the `Request` parameter of that method:

```
protected function create(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return User::create([
        'nom' => $request->name,
        'prenom' => $request->surname,
         ...
        'image' => $request->picture
    ]);
}
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, you need to change `User` to `PostUser` or vice-versa.

Comment: Ok i did that but i think it's not the correct syntax because i have this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: I tried also with this syntax : 'nom' => request('name'), but it's not working. My route in post is RegisterController@register and i havent any function call register in my RegisterController